# Can't get an access to jQuery in my scripts

Tags: theming, 8, javascript

**Edited problem description**
I develop a theme for the Drupal 8. I need to have an access to `jQuery` `$` context in my scripts, so I attached it in `libraries` as it says in docs.

```
global-styling:
    version: VERSION
    css:
        theme:
            libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css: {}
            css/layout.css: {}

    js:
        libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
        libs/autohiding-navbar/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.js: {}
        js/global.js: {}

    dependencies:
        - core/jquery
```

But in the Chrome console I get an error that jQuery context `$` isn't available.

Comment: Which one(s) load? Which one(s) don't?

Comment: This `libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}` loads, others didn't load. CSS and dependencies load perfectly.

Comment: Just to be sure: your file contains no tabs but spaces, right?

Comment: @Jaypan, I found an error. The Drupal caches it, although, it disabled in configs.

Comment: But now, I have one yet problem. The jQuery `$` context isn't available in my scripts. I'm a noobie in this. How can I get an access to `jQuery`?

Comment: Open up a new thread for that, and i'll answer it there. It's a separate question from this one.

Comment: @Jaypan, I edited this because the previous problem will not helpful for others. It's my mistake only.

Comment: The duplicate was asked for D7 but the answer hasn't changed. Drupal enables no conflict mode for jQuery, so the global `$` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Clive, Do I need to use `noConflicts` then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You need to use `jQuery`, or if you're more comfortable using `$`, assign jQuery to a var with that name in your current scope. There's an example in the duplicate

Comment: I already made it. All works perfectly! Thank you for an explanation!